# Tomcat is processing requests for a JRuby on Rails app before app is completely loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tomcat, jruby

I have an edge case, although a very customer visible one, where Tomcat begins processing requests before all dependencies are properly loaded for a Ruby on Rails stack running underneath JRuby.

Once Tomcat is restarted, there is something similar to the following happening:

```
undefined method `utc_offset' for nil:NilClass
 [RAILS_ROOT]/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:206:in `<=>'
```

This happens when the following code is invoked on one of my services:

```
  @timezones = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

If you wait a few more seconds and refresh the requesting page, it'll load no problem.

Is there a way to ensure that Tomcat does not start processing these requests until the entire stack, ActiveSupport, ActiveRecord etc is loaded? Has anyone experienced any similar symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a possible bug in JRuby-Rack, assuming that's what you're using to run your Rails app in Tomcat. JRuby-Rack is supposed to load the entirety of config/environment.rb before it will process requests, so I'm not sure how this would happen to you, but perhaps I've overlooked something. Could you share some more data (or maybe code or an app that reproduces the issue) about how you induced the error at http://kenai.com/jira/browse/JRUBY_RACK or http://bugs.jruby.org?

Comment: Hi Nick. I'm going to go ahead and open a bug as you suggested. I am indeed using Tomcat as my application server. We explicitly require active_support in environment.rb and this still happens. A stand alone application might be possible, but difficult to replicate. This is in a huge app (probably one of the larger JRuby apps out there). I'd love to contact you offline with more information and come back here eventually to post the answer if we find one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is something like that in Tomcat directly, but you can write a `javax.servlet.Filter` that will intercept all requests, and deny them until your application is loaded. When application is fully loaded, you ask filter to stop denying requests. (This isn't pure Ruby solution though).